# Plotting Date fails on x-axis and extension to subplots

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot some data but somehow the data showed on the x-axis is not the proper format. Instead having 2018-01-03 etc I am receiving 0028-02-23. When loading the data the proper format is already loaded when getting the data from the csv file.

In addition I would like to have the data plotted in diverse subplots means valuegroup in subplot 1, valuegroub B in subplot 2 etc.

The figure looks like

[image]

The code like:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

csv_loader = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/micha/Desktop/Test.csv', encoding='cp1252', parse_dates=['Date'], sep=';', index_col=0).dropna()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
csv_loader.groupby('Valuegroup').plot(x='Date', y='Value', ax=ax, legend=False, kind='line')
plt.grid(True)   
myFmt = DateFormatter("%Y-%m-%d")
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(myFmt) 
plt.show()
```

The data looks like:

> ```
> Calcgroup;Valuegroup;id;Date;Value
> Group1;A;1;20080103;0.1
> Group1;A;1;20080104;0.3
> Group1;A;1;20080107;0.5
> Group1;A;1;20080108;0.9
> Group1;B;1;20080103;0.5
> Group1;B;1;20080104;1.3
> Group1;B;1;20080107;2.0
> Group1;B;1;20080108;0.15
> Group1;C;1;20080103;1.9
> Group1;C;1;20080104;2.1
> Group1;C;1;20080107;2.9
> Group1;C;1;20080108;0.45
> ```

and after importing I have this dataframe:

```
csv_loader
          Valuegroup  id       Date  Value
Calcgroup                                 
Group1             A   1 2008-01-03   0.10
Group1             A   1 2008-01-04   0.30
Group1             A   1 2008-01-07   0.50
Group1             A   1 2008-01-08   0.90
Group1             B   1 2008-01-03   0.50
Group1             B   1 2008-01-04   1.30
Group1             B   1 2008-01-07   2.00
Group1             B   1 2008-01-08   0.15
Group1             C   1 2008-01-03   1.90
Group1             C   1 2008-01-04   2.10
Group1             C   1 2008-01-07   2.90
Group1             C   1 2008-01-08   0.45
```

Comment: Just two thoughts about your dataframe: I would disadvise to use such a column like your `Calcgroup` as index; an index should provide a unique access to a single row in your dataframe. And then - IMO - `csv_reader` is not a proper name for a pandas dataframe; it would be a good description for the `pd.read_csv` function, but not for its return vale

Answer (score 0):

Try out this solution

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

csv_loader = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/micha/Desktop/Test.csv', encoding='cp1252', parse_dates=['Date'], sep=';', index_col=0)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
csv_loader.groupby('Valuegroup').plot(x='Date', y='Value', ax=ax, legend=False, kind='line')
plt.grid(True)

myFmt = DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)

fig.autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I was not able to find what's going wrong with this date format in your code, but however, when at least testing my approch for plotting in separate subplots, which you also asked for, I saw that the formating problem was gone and the automatic format was already the one you want to have:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, sharex=True, sharey=True)
for i, (name, grp) in enumerate(csv_loader.groupby('Valuegroup')):
    axs[i].plot(grp.Date, grp.Value)
    axs[i].set_title(name)
plt.tight_layout()
```

see yourself:

[image]